# Frontend AJAX Request causes Error: 'Call to undefined function add_action'

Tags: plugins, ajax, actions, wp-localize-script

I wrote a little plugin that is supposed to handle a form submission and send some mails. When the form is submitted the request fails.

Im on a local MAMP Environment and my PHP error log shows me this error which is triggered in the main.php.

I couldn't find a way to fix this, why is add_action not available in this context? Do I need to place the add_action calls elsewhere?

error

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action()
```

plugin/main.php

```
function my_enqueue() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/script.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' ); // this line causes the error

function send_emails() {
// do stuff
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_mails', 'send_mails' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_mails', 'send_mails' ); // trigger for not logged in users as well
```

plugin/script.js

```
$.ajax({
      url: the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: 'send_mails'
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log("success");
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log("error");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false
      }
    });
```

Comment: main.php is the unique PHP file of your plugin ? and is your plugin activated in the page "plugins" ?

Comment: yes and yes @mmm

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code, the problem is most likely some other place. Have you checked that the request is actully sent to the right url?

Comment: I think I got it to work now. 
My preventDefault wasn't triggered because it was at the wrong spot. I had to remove the action of the form and prevent the default behaviour of button type submit causing a page reload...